# jQuery DataTables - Newly added rows are not visible to external filter

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a view in a webapp that uses the jQuery DataTable plugin to display data.  Part of the view functionality is to insert new rows, which correspond to a database record.

In addition, I have two dropdown select lists where the user can filter the existing data on two columns. My issue is that when adding a new row to the table via `fnAddRow(..)`, the new row data is not visible to the filters.

When inserting a new row, I use

```
var element = $("#datatable").dataTable().fnAddData([row1, row2, row3 ... ]);
var settings = $("#datatable").dataTable().fnSettings();
var n = settings.aoData[element[0]].nTr;
n.setAttribute("id", "row_id_#");

$("#datatable").dataTable().fnDraw()
```

This ensures that the search filter text input can process the new row data, but the same data is invisible to the dropdown selection actions.  The basic filtering action is implemented via

```
$("#datatable").dataTable().fnFilter(searchText, column#);
```

Is there a way to ensure that new row data in a table will be accessible by the filtering function above?

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this? I'm having the same issue. Dynamically adding rows through JS, and not being able to use the search filters on them.

Comment: No, I haven't.  I was taken off that project shortly after I posted the question and never had an opportunity to do any in-depth investigation for a solution.  If this still keeps occuring for you, it might be a good idea to submit a bug report to the DataTables project